# Dynamic CSS multi-columns list inside a fixed width container

Tags: html, css

I want to build a list with x-axis overflow in which every list element is displayed in a new column inside the parent div, this jsfiddle has an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/h06h5jzy/1/

This is my current code:

```
#testDiv{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#DDD;
}

ul{
  width:100%
  list-stype-type:none;
  padding:0;
  overflow:visible;
}

ul li{
  width:100%;
  background:blue;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
```

Using the CSS multi-column attribute won't work because I'll have a dynamic number of elements on the list. I also tried float:left for the list elements, without success.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```css
#testDiv {}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

ul li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">

  <ul>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>Testing</li>

  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: I want one element on each column

Comment: I edited answer. Change overflow: visible; to overflow: hidden; if you want ul to cut off at a certain width